# How to align my right hand side Latex? (New to LaTeX)

Tags: alignment

[image]

I'm new to LaTeX, and I encountered the alignment issue in the following picture. Are there any method that I can use to align my paragraph and math content? Any help would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX. We ask for a [Minimum Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that helps to assess your problem and then give recommendations.

Comment: By default, LaTeX justifies text. Both `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` align text to the left and to the right, respectively. Standard `equation` environment puts equations at the centre. If you load `amsmath`, you will gain access to other environments with further formatting. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: It looks like the expression beginning `\sin(\beta)` is entered as a single math expression, which is unable (without help) to break at the end of the line.  If you will show us the actual input, someone can help.  That's why we ask for a "minimum (non)working example".  Without the actual code, we're just guessing, and our crystal balls aren't working.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a guess at your code (it's much easier to help if you post it and don't make us guess).  The following gives your output:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Lower case Greek letters are written as $\omega$ $\delta$ etc. while upper case Greek letters are written as $\Omega$ $\Delta$.

Mathematical operators are prefixed with a backslash as $\sin(\beta),\cos(\alpha),\log(x)$,etc.
\end{document}
```

The log file also says `Overfull \hbox (37.85667pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--6`, indicating that it's not that the first line isn't aligned, but that the third line is running over the margin.  This is because TeX doesn't break lines in the middle of math because it's too hard to tell how to sensibly do that.  Instead, it expects you to give it some hints.  In this case, the operators are separate mathematical entities, and the commas aren't part of the math.  Ignoring the grammar of Greek letters with only a space between them, you should use `\`  (backslash space) after the `etc.` so that TeX uses interword spacing, not intersentence spacing.  This:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Lower case Greek letters are written as $\omega$ $\delta$ etc.\ while upper case Greek letters are written as $\Omega$ $\Delta$.

Mathematical operators are prefixed with a backslash as $\sin(\beta)$, $\cos(\alpha)$, $\log(x)$, etc.
\end{document}
```

produces:
[image: output]

Comment: +1. However, your claim that "TeX doesn't break lines in the middle of [inline] math because it's too hard to tell how to sensibly do that." is a bit too sweeping. In principle, TeX *can* insert linebreaks inside inline-math material. It so happens, though, that the string `$\sin(\beta),\cos(\alpha),\log(x)$` does *not* by default contain any permissible linebreak points. Anyway, `$\sin(\beta)$, $\cos(\alpha)$, $\log(x)$,` is definitely the way to go.